# How do I vertically align the input field in a form?

Tags: html, css

[image: Input text field in form]

Hi,

How do I align the input field such that they start on the same vertical line? Is there a CSS method I can use instead of manually editing each input field?

This is the html code:

```
 <form id="survey-form"> 
    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name: </label> 
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="full name" required></input><br> 
    </div> 

    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="email" id="email-label"> Email: </label> 
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="validated email" required></input><br> 
    </div>

    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="number" id="number-label"> Contact: </label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="contact" min="00000000" max="99999999" placeholder="phone number"></input><br> 
    </div>
 </form>
```

For CSS, I currently only have:

```
input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 10%;
}
```

I was wondering how I can code it in CSS such that the text input fields align? For example, if I use padding the text fields will still not aligned as the length of the label differs.

Comment: Please provide your html & css code for this particular form.

Comment: Hi, I have included my code. Thank you

Comment: Ok noted, have added an answer for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **flex property** to align the label and input box

```
#form-group{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
#form-group label{
  flex:1;
  flex-basis:20%;
  max-width:20%;
}
#form-group input {
  flex:2;
  flex-basis:20%;
  max-width:20%;
}
```

**Working Demo**

```css
#form-group{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
#form-group label{
  flex:1;
  flex-basis:20%;
  max-width:20%;
}
#form-group input {
  flex:2;
  flex-basis:20%;
  max-width:20%;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form"> 
    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name: </label> 
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="full name" required>
    </div> 

    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="email" id="email-label"> Email: </label> 
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="validated email" required>
    </div>

    <div id="form-group"> 
      <label for="number" id="number-label"> Contact: </label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="contact" min="00000000" max="99999999" placeholder="phone number">
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: if you change thw width of label and input to change in both   `flex-basis:20%;max-width:20%;` as your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need to close your input as `</input>`.

Also, in the last input, you forgot your `<div id="form-group">`.

Now, the idea to make all the input align is simply to make all your labels as an inline-block element with a specific width. That way, it will push out all the input and align them after the width ends.

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 10%;
}

#form-group label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div id="form-group">
    <label for="name" id="name-label"> Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="full name" required><br>
  </div>

  <div id="form-group">
    <label for="email" id="email-label"> Email: </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="validated email" required><br>
  </div>

  <div id="form-group">
    <label for="number" id="number-label"> Contact: </label>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="contact" min="00000000" max="99999999" placeholder="phone number">
  </div>
</form>
```